# Using same pickerView for two buttons returning empty data

Tags: ios, swift, pickerview

Here's my code . I am trying to use `UIPickerview` for few buttons with different data. but it show's me blank gray picker view when I run my project. some told me that I have to reload the pickerView but I used it for example "mainPV.delegate = self ..... Please I need help guys if someone can help me

```
import UIKit

class SearchBuyVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var optionV: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var doneBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBtn: UIButton!

    // picker view
    @IBOutlet var mainPV: UIPickerView! // main
    @IBOutlet var secPV: UIPickerView! //type
    @IBOutlet var minPV: UIPickerView! //priceMin



    @IBOutlet weak var typeBtn: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var PriceMinBtn: UIButton!

    var optionSelector = 0
    let searchData = ["Search by Areas", "Search by Map", "Search by LRT/MRTs", "Search by Schools", "Search by Propery Name"]

    let typeData = ["All Residental", "All Commerical"]
    let minNum = ["Any", "100 k", "200 k", "300 k", "400 k", "500 k", "600k ", "700 k"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setUpNav(arrowType: 2)

       mainPV = UIPickerView()
       secPV = UIPickerView()
        minPV = UIPickerView()
       mainPV.delegate = self
        secPV.delegate = self
        minPV.delegate = self

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        //Dispose of any resources that
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)
    }

    @IBAction func selectOptionsPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        openOptions()
        mainPV.delegate = self
        secPV.delegate = self
        minPV.delegate = self

    }

    @IBAction func typeSelect(_ sender: Any) {
        openOptions()
        mainPV.delegate = self
        secPV.delegate = self
        minPV.delegate = self
    }


    @IBAction func minPriceBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        openOptions()
        mainPV.delegate = self
        secPV.delegate = self
        minPV.delegate = self

    }








    @IBAction func donePressed(_ sender: Any) {
        switch optionSelector {
        case 0:
            FiltersController.instance.showAreaFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
        case 1:
            FiltersController.instance.showMapFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
        case 2:
            FiltersController.instance.showTrainStations(nc: self.navigationController!)
        case 3:
            FiltersController.instance.showSchoolFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
        default:
            FiltersController.instance.showNameFilter(nc: self.navigationController!)
        }
        closeOptions()
    }

    func openOptions() {
        optionV.isHidden = false
        mainPV.isHidden = false
        minPV.isHidden = false
        doneBtn.isHidden = false
        secPV.isHidden = false
    }

    func closeOptions(){
        optionV.isHidden = true
        mainPV.isHidden = true
        minPV.isHidden = true
        doneBtn.isHidden = true
        secPV.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBAction func nextPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        ListingController.instance.showBuyListing(nc: self.navigationController!)
    }
}

extension SearchBuyVC: UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {



        if pickerView == mainPV {
            return searchData.count
        }

        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView == mainPV{
            return searchData[row]
        }
        if pickerView == secPV{
            return typeData[row]

        }
        if pickerView == minPV{
            return minNum[row]
        }
        return ""
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        optionSelector = row
        if pickerView == mainPV{
            searchBtn.setTitle(searchData[row], for: .normal)
        }
        if pickerView == secPV{
            typeBtn.setTitle(typeData[row], for: .normal)
        }

        if pickerView == minPV{
            PriceMinBtn.setTitle(minNum[row], for: .normal)

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: mainPV = UIPickerView()
   secPV = UIPickerView()
    minPV = UIPickerView()
remove all this cause loading empty view and mainPV.dataSource = self
secPV.dataSource = self
minPV.dataSource = self which will show picker view all datas in each

Comment: func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        
        if pickerView == mainPV{
            return searchData.count
        }
        if pickerView == secPV{
            return typeData.count
            
        }
        if pickerView == minPV{
            return minNum.count
        }
        
        return 1
    }. pass each data clearly for each picker view

Answer (score 0):

Also need to set dataSource for the pickerViews. So that the methods of `UIPickerViewDataSource` called which are responsible for returning all the data to `UIPickerView`. Your class must to confirm the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol.

Ex:

```
picker_country.dataSource = self
```

Answer (score 0):

At first import the UIPickerView protocols within the class as,

```
class SearchBuyVC: UIViewController  UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource
```

and add the following lines also to call the datasource functions,

```
mainPV.delegate = self
secPV.delegate = self
minPV.delegate = self
mainPV.dataSource = self
secPV.dataSource = self
minPV.dataSource = self
```